# Using Event Subscriber change the product custom field value after first checkout of that product

Tags: 8, commerce, event-subscribers

Using '[Event Subscriber](https://medium.com/@sumanthkumarc/writing-event-subscriber-for-order-complete-event-in-drupal-8-commerce-2-x-196292330b1c)', I'm able to get `$order` and `$items` from the order after completing the checkout.

How can I get the product id from the `$items`and modify the product custom field value?

Scenario: I want to change the status of the product after completing the first checkout of that product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to change the status of the product or the product variation?

`$items` is an array of OrderItems. If you loop over the items, you can get the referenced purchased entity of the single item with `$purchasedEntity = $item->getPurchasedEntity();`. If you only want the first item you can access it like so `$purchasedEntity = $items[0]->getPurchasedEntity();`. 
In case the PurchasedEntity is a ProductVariation you can get the product with `$product = $purchasedEntity->getProduct();`

In case you want to change the status of the product:

```
$product->setUnpublished();
```

Or for the variation:

```
$variation->setActive(false);
```

If you want to set any custom field on the product variation:

```
$variation->set('your_custom_field_name', $value);
```

[docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aset/8.4.x)
This assumes you use the default commerce2 product architecture. It is absolutly possible that you get other purchasable entities than ProductVariations back from the OrderItem.

Comment: I have one 'select' field and i have to change the value of that. doesn't required to make product unpublished. Example: 'status' select field which has 'active and deactive'. I want to change to 'deactive' after checkout of this product.

Comment: Updated the answer for setting custom fields. Here is the [doc]  (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3Aset/8.4.x)

Comment: Thanks!! Let me try below code. 
$purchasedEntity = $item->getPurchasedEntity();
$product = $purchasedEntity->getProduct();
$product->set('field_custom', 'updated..');

Comment: Getting `Fatal error: Call to a member function getPurchasedEntity()` on null error. Can you help me to resolve.

Comment: You're welcome :D. Improved the answer for future reference. It should be more clear now, that one have to loop over the items or how one can access the first item directly.

Comment: It is resolved by adding the index $purchasedEntity = $items[0]->getPurchasedEntity(); It always single product in my scenario so loop is not required. Thanks a lot for your answer